# How to include separator after last dot on the line using substr?

Tags: php, html, regex

I've got the following code that will split the contents into three sections, with two separators in the middle, yet it is cutting in between the sentences and I'd like to split (call substr) after the last dot on that line where it is separating.

```
$separator = "<br/>";

$text = stripslashes($article_content); 
$first = ceil(strlen($text) / 3);

$string = substr($text, 0, $first);
$string .= $separator;
$string .= substr($text,$first,$first);
$string .= $separator;
$string .= substr($text,($first*2), $first);

echo $string;
```

So on the first substr where it is separating, it would only include the separator after the dot on that line, so that it does not break the sentence. I looked at www.php.net/substr‎ but it didn't help.

### EDIT

I was able to make the dot work but currently can't figure out how to include in the next line break.

```
$separator = "<br/>";

$text = stripslashes($article_content); 
$start = ceil(strlen($text) / 3);

$string = substr($text,0, strpos($text, '.', $start)+1); EDITED HERE
$string .= $separator;
$string .= substr($text,$start,$start);
$string .= $separator;
$string .= substr($text,($start*2), $start);
echo $string;
```

Comment: can we see some sample input and output ?

Comment: Does the slightly modified line of your first question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698990/how-to-break-mysql-contenttexthtml-content-into-columns $first = strpos($text,".",strlen($text) / 2); not work?

Comment: No, that would just split it in two, still not on any sentence end.

Comment: If you use `strpos($text, '.', $start)+1`, you need to do 2 things. First, set `$firstdot = strpos($text, '.', $start);` <check for error incase there was no dot, set it to $start if no dot>. Second, `$string .= $separator;` <then> `$string .= substr($text,$firstdot+1,$start*2);` <then your other lines>

Comment: The only issue with both @sln and the answer with odeone.com one is that it seems to be copying the last few words and replicating under the break, any idea why that is doing that?

Comment: Yes because it was crappy. If there is not much text "a. bbbbbbbbbbbb. c.", the result of  1/3 length + x can be the same as 2/3 length + y. Works for long text, but what kind of solution would that be...

Comment: http://ideone.com/RLimw5

Comment: My answer splits them in the closest dot near the breaks. But in the `a. bbbbbbbbbbbb. c.` example, all will fail, because he asked "split on the dot". Exceptions can be build later

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is something you are looking for, but I would use `explode()`

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

If you are sure you have 3 sentences separated by ".", use:

```
$text = explode(".", $article_content);
```

Use print_r() to debug your output, like:

```
print_r($text);
```

More info about `explode()` here:
https://www.php.net/explode

This is pretty weak solution to be honest. Firstly, you cannot be sure you have 3 sentences only and they're always separated by "dot" sign. Secondly, there might by "dot" in the middle of the sentence, that's no a full stop, for example $3.45. If I were you, I would try to include something you can separate content by, for example "\r\n" (new line sign) and then explode by this creating your parts....

Hope that helps.

Comment: This would fail if used in any context other that a 3 sentenced string. 4 or more would make this result in 1,1,n-2 length parts. Aoart from that, using arrays for string manipulation is not the best plan :)

Comment: where do you see me referring to 3 parts of string? why would you down-vote this? I specifically said, he should include some sort of separator and then explode by it to get the proper result... btw, string is an array of letters.

Comment: to be honest it's much quicker to explode by ".", then count number of elements in array and divide count() by 3. calculate how many you need to "glue" together, do implode and return array of 3 elements. you can use strlen to see which are longer than others and make pretty nice result.

Answer (score 0):

My php isin't good but maybe just do the replace instead of the first separator append

```
 $string = substr($text, 0, $first);
 $string = preg_replace( '/((?<=\.)[^.]*|)$', "<br/>$1", $string);
 $string .= substr($text,$first,$first*2);
 ...
```

The regex broken down

```
 #  ((?<=\.)[^.]*|)$

 (                      # (1 start)
      (?<= \. )              # Ensure a dot behind
      [^.]*                  # Optional non-dot's
   |                       # or
                             # nothing, then put it at the end
 )                      # (1 end)
 $                      # End of string
```

Comment: That last line does exactly nothing :P `substr(string, start, stop)`, `stop-start===0` here, so no magic

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Please note, in this case last (third) part will be in most cases shorter. You could manipulate `round()` function to round it up or down. Also, this will work assuming each sentence is separated by `"."` and there are no other occurrences of it in text.

In this example you can manipulate the number of slices you would like to have, not only 3.

```
<?php
$slices = 3;
$content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vehicula dui tempus tincidunt tincidunt. Nunc lorem arcu, blandit non blandit ut, dapibus auctor erat. Donec nec ultrices arcu, non varius risus. Aliquam lacinia ipsum neque, sit amet facilisis lorem sagittis at. Vivamus id ligula vel arcu commodo fermentum. Cras lobortis massa non ornare sagittis. Vivamus augue felis, varius nec ante sit amet, tristique venenatis ligula. Proin ac augue vel orci auctor semper eleifend sit amet orci. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam a vestibulum velit. Nam et pharetra odio. Proin feugiat in sapien ut fermentum. Donec eu arcu orci.';

$content = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode('.', $content)));
$take = round(count($content) / $slices, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

$new = array();
for ($i=0; $i < $slices; $i++) { 
    $new[] = implode('. ', array_slice($content, $i * $take, $take)) . '.';
}
$final = implode('<br>', $new);
print_r($final);
```

**Result for 14 sentences (5+5+4):**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vehicula dui tempus tincidunt tincidunt. Nunc lorem arcu, blandit non blandit ut, dapibus auctor erat. Donec nec ultrices arcu, non varius risus. Aliquam lacinia ipsum neque, sit amet facilisis lorem sagittis at.

Vivamus id ligula vel arcu commodo fermentum. Cras lobortis massa non ornare sagittis. Vivamus augue felis, varius nec ante sit amet, tristique venenatis ligula. Proin ac augue vel orci auctor semper eleifend sit amet orci. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

Nullam a vestibulum velit. Nam et pharetra odio. Proin feugiat in sapien ut fermentum. Donec eu arcu orci.

Answer (score -1):

You could take the string, and find about one third and look for the closest dot:

```
function splitInEqualParts($string, $parts=3, $seperator='<hr />'){
    $partlength= ceil(strlen($string)/ $parts);  // find proper length
    $texts = array();
    $prevCut=0;

    for($i=1; $i<$parts; $i++){
        $prev = strrpos($string, ".", $partlength); // find . in front of the break
        $next = strpos($string, ".", $partlength); // find . after the break
        $cut = $prev<=$next ? $prev : $next; // find out which dot is closest
        $texts[] = substr($string, $prevCut, $cut ); // Cut and save part of text
        $prevCut = $cut; // save for next item
    }
    $texts[] = substr($string, $prevCut+1 ); // Save the last part

    return implode($seperator, $texts);
}
```

Comment: what if you will be asked to provide 100+ slices instead of 3. this code is weak, you didn't even use any loop to achieve the result.

Comment: I didnt make a loop becaust that would complecate things. A function would be better if you're talking about what would be better :)

Comment: Did you really just downvote me because I gave comment on you code? Mine did exactly what the TS asked. That is not worth a downvote IMO (unless it's stupid).

Comment: I've downvoted your previous code because it didn't make sense to me, maybe it was working but usage of variables (=memory) was wrong and it seemed "heavy" to me. You didn't use loops or arrays. I like future proof coding, something that can be easily adapted for other cases too. Now it's much better (after editing) although you simply based your answer on mine, suddenly using arrays and loops. I am glad you're learning mate ; )